# remove front-page visitor statistics in wp statistics

Tags: wordpress

I'm using WP Statistics for my website. My front-page ("/") is at the "top pages" list. how can I remove that from "top pages"?

Here is a screenshot:

[image: this]

Comment: Consider asking your question at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ -- it's not really about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to belong on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

you can use CSS for that:

Something like:

```
table tr:nth-child(1){display:none;}
```